# twitter bootstrap horiontal nav dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

i'm using twitter bootstrap and i'm trying to make the drop-down horizontal, you can see a demo here: 
http://bit.ly/13rrJNQ

It seems to function right now as it is, but i'm looking to achieve one more thing.

I'd like the sub nav* to have a width of 100%, so the sub nav with the blue background fills the width of the page completely.

**Do you think that that doable?**

*sub nav

```
<ul id="ent-nav-dd" class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="#">sub lorem 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">sub lorem 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">sub lorem 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">sub lorem 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">sub lorem 5</a></li>
<li><a href="#">sub lorem 6</a></li>
<li><a href="#">sub lorem 7</a></li>
<li><a href="#">sub lorem 7</a></li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Twitter bootstrap applies the following CSS rule to .dropdown-menu

```
.navbar .dropdown-menu {
    margin: 0 15px;
}
```

If you override this then the sub menu items should be full width